# python why i cannot read from file i just created?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to create a program that sorts some words.
when i try to reopen a file that i just created nothing happens.
if i copy paste the file under different name and try to open it everything is OK.

```
    import itertools
    import codecs
    filepath = 'greekdic.txt'
    filepathtemp= 'temp.txt'
    filepathtemptwo = 'final.txt'
    filepathtempread = 'greekdic2.txt'
    ######################## INPUT #################################################
    chars = str(input("Enter letters: "))
    chars2=chars
    count = int(input("Enter lenght of word: "))
    count2=count
    x=0
    ######################## CREATE TEMP FILE WITH INTEREST WORDS #################
    file = codecs.open(filepathtemp, "w", "utf-8")
    with codecs.open(filepath, "r", "utf-8") as fp:  
       line = fp.readline().splitlines()
       cnt = 1
       while line:
        a=len(line[0])
        if a == count:
            print(line)
            file.write(line[0])
            file.write("\n")
        line = fp.readline().splitlines()
        cnt += 1
    ###########################################################################
    file = codecs.open(filepathtemptwo, "w", "utf-8")
    with codecs.open(filepathtemp, "r", "utf-8") as fp:  
       line = fp.readline().splitlines()
       cnt = 1
       while line:
        for x in range(count):
            if chars[x] == line[0][0]:
                print ("***********************************")
                print(line)
                file.write(line[0])
                file.write("\n")       
        line = fp.readline().splitlines()
        cnt += 1
    ########################## SEARCH ########################################
    print(chars)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        for item in itertools.product(chars2, repeat=count2):
            ppp = "".join(item)
            #print(ppp)
---------->>>>>> ***with codecs.open(filepathtemptwo, "r", "utf-8") as fp2:***
                line1 = fp2.readline().splitlines()
                #print(line1[0])
                #print(ppp)
                cnt = 1
                while line1:
                    if str(ppp) == str(line1[0]):
                        print("--------------------------------------------")
                        print("value of line1 is: ")
                        print(line1[0])
                        print(id(line1[0]))
                        print("value of ppp is: ")
                        print(ppp)
                        print(id(ppp))
                    line1 = fp2.readline().splitlines()
                    cnt += 1
```

the problem lies on "filepathtemptwo" that is just created. if i copy paste the contents in other file is ok. i even change the variable names using new ones.
can anyone help.

Comment: You never call `.close()` on `file`. Presumably the buffer doesn't get flushed to the file and, what's more, you go on to redefine `file`

Comment: @roganjosh: spot on. Interesting observation

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for the answer.. The .Close() command was only for testing if that was the problem and I forgot tou remove it. What do you mean redefine the file. I already used file.flush() and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You've misinterpreted both of my points. Firstly I am saying that you _need_ `file.close()`, but you never do it. Second, I am saying that you have `file = codecs.open(filepathtemp, "w", "utf-8")` _and_ `file = codecs.open(filepathtemptwo, "w", "utf-8")` (redefining `file`). Both of these mean that you never flush the contents to the file. Python may have a file buffer that you flush, but there's also an OS one.